# How to display a tree-view in React without any library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tree, treeview

I have a react app which has to be displayed in tree-view format.

At the top we should have a parent/root node.When the user clicks on a button the children for that node should be shown(not subchildren , children only). And similarly clicking on a child should show its children components(and so on).The height of the tree is N levels deep where N is between 10-15.

Can someone suggest some resource to implement this?

Implementation to be done without using any kind of library.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @szczocik The main thing I am stuck in is implementing the toggle when user clicks on  a particular node..Not only the children but the subchildren of the node should disappear.

Comment: If you remove the child from the DOM, it's subchildren will be gone as well, right? They are rendered inside of the child anyway.

Comment: I am not thinking of removing but just hiding them using css.. @szczocik

Comment: Don't. React gives you a wonderful thing called conditional renders where you can show some specific components based on some state. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html